# Python Scrapy - XPath for nested table tags

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

This is my source code:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="border-left: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153); border-right: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td height="511">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0" height="500">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="1%" valign="top" height="500">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" bordercolor="#CCCCCC" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr bgcolor="#BB375F" bordercolor="#CCCCCC">
```

How do I write an XPath to reach the innermost `<tr>` tag?

Here's what I've tried:

```
top_table = response.xpath("//table[4]/tbody/tr/td")
content_table = top_table.xpath("table")
print content_table
```

And this is the output I'm getting:

`[ < Selector xpath='table' data=u' < table width="100%" border="0" cellspaci' > ]`

Basically I'm able to get to the penultimate table in the first line and the innermost table is what I want to reach. Not sure how to proceed or where I'm going wrong?
Any help or suggestions will be welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Basically I'm able to get to the penultimate table in the first line and the innermost table is what I want to reach.

One possible way to get inner-most `table` generally is by making sure the candidate `table` doesn't have descendant `table` element :

```
//table[not(.//table)]
```

so I would suggest to try something like this to get `tr/td` from the inner-most `table` :

```
top_table = response.xpath("//table[not(.//table)]/tbody/tr/td")
```